# How do I change the game speed during a match in Starcraft 2 (SC2)?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was in a game the other day and I saw

```
"<Player> has voted to increase the game speed (fast)"
"<Player> has voted to increase the game speed (faster)"
```

I don't remember the player's name, but it was show in place of `<Player>`.

This was right after the game started.

I'm still in "beginner" mode, too, so I was a bit surprised to see this.

When I look at my hotkeys, I see entries for `Increase Game Speed` and `Decrease Game Speed` but there's no keys bound to them.

Does anyone know how to change the game speed during a SP/MP match?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a custom map?

Comment: Odge, positive :)

Comment: Maybe all you need to do is to bound the hotkey and press it in game?

Comment: @Buss I tried this, but for some reason I'm unable to change bound hotkeys one at a time. Only with the drop down selecting a theme.

Comment: i remember back in the day of WC3 that some people trying to be dicks would send chat msgs like this trying to trick you into thinking the game was doing something, like "<Your name> will be revealed in 20 seconds!" hoping to make you panic.

Answer (score 4):

This can only be done in practice league.  To do it, hit `f10` --> `options` --> `Gameplay`, then slide the "game speed" slider to the desired speed.

You may also get a message saying *"XXX is slowing down the game..."* in a dialog box, which has to be closed by hand.  This can happen even in league games - it is simply (a very poorly thought-out message) trying to explain why any perceived lag is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you were in the practice league still. There is no way to change the game speed of a ranked ladder match or placement match.

I'll try to look into how you can do it while in practice league, but it will be made a tad more difficult by me not being in it.

Comment: downvoted, this happens to me in ladder games as well. I haven't noticed a speed change, but the message appears.

Comment: @zmf Are you sure the player wasn't just typing it? Post a screencap and I might believe you. I have about 300 matches of ranked SC2 play and have never seen it. If I bring up the gamespeed option in game there is a message about faster being the only speed available for ladder play.

Comment: pretty sure it wasn't typed; i noticed it again last night ...  a green dialog appears on screen stating that <player x> is slowing down the game. If i think about it i'll try to get a screen cap, or reproduce. I've inadvertently triggered the message myself, i suspect it was the -/+ keys.

Comment: Slowing down the game means your computer can't handle what is going on in the game. You can easily trigger it if you try a 4v4 and have 8 pop cap armies meet up and fight...preferably with lots of little units like zerglings and marines.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done in a Custom/Hosted game. The MAP doesn't need to be custom, and probably wasn't, but you can't adjust the game speed in a ranked match.

Comment: Okay, but HOW do you do it? What's the hotkey?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have a hunch its available through a chat command like replying to messages. However, I can't find a list of battle.net chat commands that has been updated since Starcraft 2. [I wounder how I'll solve that problem.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/where-can-i-find-the-official-list-of-current-battle-net-chat-commands)</strike>

Since [chat commands have been 90% removed between SC1 and 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/where-can-i-find-the-official-list-of-current-battle-net-chat-commands), they're probably not the way this was done. Sorry for the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing through the practice league and have not been able to recreate it.  I have seen the message about the game speed changing but I have never seen it be anything other than normal so the message could be just a bug when people do vote.

I have asked at the start of almost every game (chat to all) and have yet to find anyone that knows how to do it at least in the practice league.

**UPDATE:** Played a 2v2 yesterday and the message come up saying my partner was changing the game speed but nothing changed.  I ask him what he did to cause the message and he said he hadn't done anything.  Maybe it is just a bug in the practice league.