# Where can I find the Official list of current Battle.net chat commands?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

Battle.net supports a number of chat commands. For example:

```
/w USERID Hello UserId!
```

sends "Hello UserId!" to that user. I'd like to see the current list of commands now that Starcraft 2 has come out, so that I can learn any changes, additions, or anything specific to Starcraft 2.

I have been able to find several dated, unofficial lists, but I would far prefer a current, official list, which I have not been able to find. Can anyone find one?

For reference, in case we can't find an official list, [here is the most complete old, unofficial list I found](http://www.scfreak.org/index.php/chat-commands/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only chat command that was left in Battle.net 2.0 is /r, which replies to people in-game. All other chat commands have been removed.

Comment: Possible on Starcraft I suppose, but they can't have removed all those commands from WoW! I will test some of the old ones in SC2 tonight.

Comment: If you have a party, /p works. Maybe it's a subset of the WoW commands?

Comment: Sadly, my own playing and everything I hear from others says this is true. We only have a few remaining chat commands. It could still be useful to compile them here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the official list for classic battle.net can be found [here](http://classic.battle.net/info/commands.shtml) (which appears to be the source of the link that WillfulWizard mentioned).

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. The classic list being found first makes me more concerned that @Brandon's answer is correct.